# Application of the binomial series: In what point was the Taylor series developed and how?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, physics

Let  $|\vec{r}| \gg\left|\vec{r^{\prime}}\right|$  and  $x:=\frac{\vec{r}^{2}-2 \vec{r^{2}} \cdot \vec{r^{\prime}}}{\vec{r}^{2}} $ be a small number.

$$\frac{1}{\left|\vec{r}-\vec{r^{\prime}}\right|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\vec{r}^{2}+{\vec{r^{\prime}}}^{2}-2 \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r^{\prime}}}}=\frac{1}{|\vec{r}| \sqrt{1+\frac{{\vec{r^{\prime}}}^{2}-2 \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r^{\prime}}}{\vec{r}^{2}}} }=\frac{1}{|\vec{r}| \sqrt{1+x} } $$

With the binomial Series:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}=(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=1-\frac{1}{2} x+\frac{3}{8} x^{2}-\ldots$$

we get in first order:

$$ \frac{1}{\left|\vec{r}-\vec{r^{\prime}}\right|}=\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|}+\frac{\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r^{\prime}}}{|\vec{r}|^{3}} $$

I don't understand the last step. We use the Taylor series of the binomial equation, but at what point?  Can someone explain the last step in more detail?

Comment: They replaced $\frac{1}{r\sqrt{1+x}}$ with $\frac{1}{r}(1-\frac{1}{2}x)$ (the 1st order Taylor polynomial), replaced $x$, then omitted the $\frac{(r')^2}{r^3}$ term since $r'\ll r$. (I'm not going to bother with all those bars and overscript arrows.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're happy with the equality:

$$
\frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} - \vec{r'} \rVert} = \frac{1}{ \lVert \vec{r} \rVert \sqrt{1+x}}
$$

where $x = \frac{\vec{r'}^2 - 2 \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r'}}{\vec{r}^2}$ (notice there's a typo in the first line of your question, but during the manipulation in your second line you correct it).

Using the fact that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} = (1+x)^{-1/2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{3}{8} x^2 + \ldots$$

we see (keeping only first order terms)

$$
\frac{1}{ \lVert \vec{r} \rVert} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} = 
\frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert} \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{2} x + O(x^2) \right ) \approx
\frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{x}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert}
$$

Now substituting our definition for $x$ back in, we see this is all equal to

$$
\frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\vec{r'}^2 - 2 \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r'}}{\vec{r}^2 \lVert \vec{r} \rVert}
$$

Remembering that $\vec{r}^2 = \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} = \lVert \vec{r} \lVert^2$, this becomes

$$
\frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert} - \frac{1}{2} \left (
\frac{\lVert \vec{r'} \rVert^2}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert^3} +
\frac{-2 \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r'}}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert^3} \right )
$$

But since $\lVert r' \rVert \ll \lVert r \rVert$, the $\frac{\lVert \vec{r'} \rVert^2}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert^3}$ term is small (so isn't seen in the first order terms), ignoring it we're left with

$$
\frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{-2 \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r'}}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert^3} =
\frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert} + \frac{\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r'}}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert^3}
$$

Comparing with where we started, we see (to first order)

$$
\frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} - \vec{r'} \rVert} \approx \frac{1}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert} + \frac{\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r'}}{\lVert \vec{r} \rVert^3}
$$

as claimed.

---

I hope this helps ^_^